# Selling item from one region to another via Gold Auction House?

Tags: diablo-iii

is this possible?

e.g. I want to sell a magic weapon from Europe server to my friend in USA server

Answer (score 3):

No.

Source: http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/5051765311

> Please note that characters, items, and friends lists do not transfer across regions. Playing on a different region's servers means you'll be creating characters and friends lists specifically for that region, and **you'll be accessing the gold-based auction house for that region.**

Answer (score 0):

No, this is impossible. The Auction Houses are region based and items have to stay in your region.